# Surreal CMS + Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I built an application using Laravel 9, then a simple site was built inside of the same Laravel installation.

Now I have the request to integrate Surreal CMS to edit the site, is the first time that I use Surreal CMS, and based on the things that I saw, looks like just need some FTP credentials to edit the views.

In surreal CMS you should be able to previsualize the content of pages but due to the nature of routing in Laravel looks like surreal CMS is not able to open views

I have my routes under web.php just to redirect to the view for the site for example /about redirects to my blade file using  `Route::view('/', 'about');`

But looks like surreal cms is trying to open something like /about.php

Is there a secure way how can expose my views to be accessible without using web.php file? I'm assuming that maybe I need to use .htaccess and obviously remove my blade code to use just PHP.

Or better question, what is the best approach to integrate pages for my site but that Laravel will not be involved but both are hosted in the same place?

All these pages are very simple so are not pulling anything from the backend

Comment: I think it's trying to look for a view file and it has nothing to do with `web.php` but I can't seem to make sense out of the Surreal CMS documentation.

Comment: In the end, I just moved the files for the site to the public folder to be accessible for Surreal CMS, and kept the index.php for Laravel and in route file redirect to another file that acts as the index for the site